# Can I set a user of AWS CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I want to be able to set the "deploying" user on CodeDeploy instead of doing everything as root. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to run as any other user but root from the CodeDeploy service or the agent. Installing software usually requires root privileges and at the very least running processes as another user generally does.

If you want to restrict the agent's effective permissions, you might want to look into SElinux. You can use SElinux to limit the access of the host agent's executables. The host agent is capable of setting contexts on files if you choose to use SElinux generally.

After all that, if you really want to run the CodeDeploy agent as another user, try the following:

1. Install the host agent normally.
2. Stop the host agent.
3. Remove the updater cron tab file so it doesn't relaunch the agent as root. You will have to manually check for and update the agent, since all vended versions assume you want to run as root.
4. Change ownership of everything in `/opt/codedeploy-agent/` to the user you want to run as.
5. Run `/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent start`.

You will also need to make sure that you don't attempt to specify run as user or file permissions in your appspec, since the agent may not be able to do those actions but it will try to anyway.

Comment: thanks!  I need to run commands like bundle install which are best executed by non-root users. What's the best way yo go about it?

Comment: while we're on the topic - do you guys have any sample appspecs for Ruby/Rails deployment?